# How to authenticate using requests in python3 for futher parsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, authentication

I'm trying to login on [this](https://accounts.pixiv.net/login) page using requests in python3. 
Found a [POST-request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFAWj.jpg) in a browser which I'm probably need to imitate.

I copied the headers and created a requests.session, see the code below:

```py
import requests
import os

header = {
'accept': 'application/json',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'connection': 'keep-alive',
'content-length': '596',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'host': 'accounts.pixiv.net',
'referer': 'https://accounts.pixiv.net/login',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'}

login_page_url = 'https://accounts.pixiv.net/login'
target_url = 'https://accounts.pixiv.net/
api/login?lang=en'
login = 'MY_LOGIN'
password = 'MY_PASS'

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = header
first_resp = session.get(login_page_url)
second_resp = session.post(target_url, auth=(login, password))

print(second_resp)
print(second_resp.text)
```

But when I run this script, it just freezes for like 5 minutes and then exits with `.ConnectionError` instead of `Response[200]` or something, and I really don't have any idea why

Comment: `auth=(username, password)` is specifically for HTTP Basic Authentication.  Does that website use HTTP Basic Authentication?  A lot of sites don't.

Comment: Don't use `.headers`, this site uses `<form action="/login"`, search for `requests form login`

Comment: @JohnGordon To be honest I didn't know that there's different types of authentication, is there an easy way to distinguish one from another?

Comment: Based on @stovfl's comment, it looks like that site doesn't use it, but instead uses a plain form to log in.